# send a value in html a tag, to open a modal window for specific product

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I have a for loop maintained which makes a link for each product in database as:

```
<a href='#openModal' class='btn btn-primary' >View Details</a>
```

When someone clicks the link view Details, A modal window pops up. I need to show details of specific product. I have a single modal window #openmodal, but many links as there are many products, for each product there is uniques, product_id though in database.

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" >
<div style="">
    <h2>Details<a href="#close" title="Close" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">X</a></h2><hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-col-lg-12 col-sm-12" >
            <div class="row">
                <b>Added On:</b> date here<br />
                <b>Description:</b> <p>description here.</p><br />
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal window opens smooth but how make it show a specific product, depending upon link clicked.

Thank you in advance.. any type of help will be apriciated.

Comment: Are you using jquery? you wold probably have to send some data back to the controller to get that specific record

Comment: no, modal window is purely html5 and css3 code. and code behind for generating links for each product is c#, as innerhtml code.

Comment: unless there is a modal for each product already rendered at page load, you would have to query to get record information

Comment: there is a single modal window.. and all the product view link should access the same modal window with its product_id, so i can get the details for that certain product only in the modal..

can there be something like <a href="#modalopen" id= "i"> view details </a>
where i would represent product_id in each loop and access the value of i, inside modal window when it is called...

Comment: yes but what I am saying is to get a records details you are going to have to use some kind of javascript to pull the data using the ID...html cant do that alone

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. yes i needed js.. :)

Answer (score 0):

So I will have lik for every product i have and their id will be the product id:

```
 <a href='#openModal' id='"+ ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]   +"'onClick='configurator(this)' class='btn btn-primary' >View Details</a>
```

Now I will call the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">


                                                    function configurator(clicked) {

                                                        alert(clicked.id);
                                                    }
```

to get the product id. and i will use this product id in my modal window.